# Problem obtaining Orientation using MetadataExtractor GetDescription

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, metadata-extractor

### Objective

I want to "correct" the orientation of an image.  My plan is to extract the orientation from the Exif data stored with the image and use that to inform a re-orientation of the image.

### Problem

It's probably me, but for this particular Exif property, the GetDescription (or GetString) simply returns null; all other properties that I have tried (x15) return a value.  In the sample code below (a Console App), "Approach 1" uses the preferred and efficient `GetDescription` approach to grab the image Orientation, while "Approach 2" uses an inefficient `foreach` loop to iterate through directories and tags searching for the Orientation.

```
using MetadataExtractor;
using MetadataExtractor.Formats.Exif;

string Filename = @"D:\Users\Simon\OneDrive\My Stuff\My Source\TestFuelPriceTracker\Originals\IMG_8490.jpg";

IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(Filename);

// Approach 1
var subIfdDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
var Orientation1 = subIfdDirectory?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation);
Console.WriteLine($"Approach 1: Orientation = \"{Orientation1}\"");

// Approach 2
foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
    {
        switch (tag.Name)
        {
            case "Orientation":
                Console.WriteLine($"Approach 2: Orientation = \"{tag.Description}\"");
                break;
        }
    }
}

// Approach 3
var Orientation2 = directories
    .OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>()
    .FirstOrDefault(s => string.Equals(s?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation), "Orientation", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine($"Approach 3: Orientation = \"{Orientation2}\"");
```

When run, I get the following results...

```
Approach 1: Orientation = ""
Approach 2: Orientation = "Top, left side (Horizontal / normal)"
Approach 3: Orientation = ""
```

Approach 2 shows that the Orientation information is actually present in the image.  Please note that I have tried numerous images and I get the same problem.  Not sure if this is relevant, but all images were taken on an iPhone 12.

Approach 3 added based on a suggestion by @aybe.

### Environment

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 11 Professional machine, all software patched to latest versions.  The framework is .NET 6.  MetadataExtractor version 2.7.2.

Comment: I'd use something like that or so: `directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().First(s=> string.Equals(s?.GetDescription(...), "Whatever", OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @aybe  Not sure that will fly because of the nested list of tags within each directory.  I plugged it into the sample and it comes up with ```Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element```.  Nice try though.

Comment: Sorry I meant `FirstOrDefault`. However, there's nothing wrong with approach #2 unless of course you realize it takes much longer than #1.

Comment: @aybe  That makes sense!  :-)  Unfortunately the result is the same as Approach 1.  I have edited the original post and added your idea in as "Approach 3".

Comment: I've done a quick test and I vaguely remind of one thing, this information may not be present, guess what, on all the files I've tried, neither had it!

Comment: @aybe  I thought that to start with, but then that does not explain why when I iterate through the Exif properties the orientation is available (as in Approach 2).  I have numerous images with a number of them whose orientation needs adjusting.  Using the ```foreach``` approach I can see the orientation information and it seems to correlate to each image's orientation.  It's just the ```GetDescription``` approach that returns null.  And it seems only for this property.

Comment: I guess I'm starting to understand, some of the images may have it in IPTC rather than EXIF, hence why it's safer to iterate through all of them.

Comment: I have found the error to your problem, it's deceptively simple, string equals overload is object and tag orientation is an int, thus, it'll never match "Orientation" 

Comment: [Property item descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions) => `PropertyTagOrientation`, `PropertyTagThumbnailOrientation` => `ValueType: Short`

Comment: @Jimi This is interesting but there's no GDI for .NET 6 as far as I can tell

Comment: It doesn't matter, those are standard (international) values. The section of the Orientation Tag is not JPEG or SUB IFD, it's EXIF (IFD0). I.e., `.OfType<ExifIfd0Directory>().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Jimi Not sure what you mean, nobody is talking about JPEG but only EXIF.

Comment: @aybe Did I say anything different? It's about the section that contains the information. It's `... = directories.OfType<ExifIfd0Directory>().FirstOrDefault()?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation);` -- So, `ExifIfd0Directory`, not `ExifSubIfdDirectory`.

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right, I realized that with the sample I've posted.

Comment: @aybe You could ignore the section Type entirely and write, e.g., `var orientation = directories.FirstOrDefault(dir => dir.ContainsTag(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation))?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation);`

Comment: I've already deleted the project.

Comment: @aybe @jimi in your comments above I believe you have hit the problem I was facing... (1) @aybe pointing out that Orientation is in fact an ```int```, and (2) @jimi pointing out that the Exif directory is in fact "EXIF IFD0" and not "EXIF SubIFD" as I had in my sample code.  Good spots!

Comment: Based on the above two points... I can first look in the correct directory (doh!)... EXIF D0 and pull back an integer value using something like ```Orientation = ifd0Directory.TryGetInt32(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation, out int value) ? value : -1;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposed final solution is...

```
IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(Filename);
var ifd0Directory = directories.OfType<ExifIfd0Directory>().FirstOrDefault();
int Orientation = -1;
if (ifd0Directory != null) {
    Orientation = ifd0Directory.TryGetInt32(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation, out int value) ? value : -1;
}
```

If successful it returns an integer value from 1 to 8 inclusive, or -1 if there is a problem.  For anyone whose interested, the meaning of these numbers is discussed well in the following article...

[JPEG Image Orientation and Exif](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/31/image_rotation_exif_info/)

I would also point you at the following MIT paper which has captured the data types for each of the Exif tags; along with a lot of other good information too...

[Description of Exif file format](https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html)

Comment: Note that `ifd0Directory` can be null. You're not handling that. -- The range of values of the Orientation Tag is `(1;8)`. You can also see it [in the MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions#propertytagorientation) I linked before (and rectangles have 4 sides :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code would never work because it was comparing the integer value of the tag, that would of course never match `"Orientation"`.

This works but with how this might fail as some images don't necessarily have the tags as I said, it might be worth looking at computing the orientation either from other tags or from image dimensions as a fallback solution.

```
private static void GetOrientation(Stream stream)
{
    var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(stream);

    if (TryGetOrientationTag(directories, out var result))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Compute orientation from image size instead");
    }
}

private static bool TryGetOrientationTag(IEnumerable<Directory> directories, out string result)
{
    result = null!;

    foreach (var directory in directories)
    {
        switch (directory)
        {
            case ExifDirectoryBase e:
                foreach (var tag in e.Tags)
                {
                    if (tag.Type is not ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation || tag.Description is null)
                        continue;

                    result = tag.Description;
                    return true;
                }

                break;
            case IptcDirectory i:
                foreach (var tag in i.Tags)
                {
                    if (tag.Type is not IptcDirectory.TagImageOrientation || tag.Description is null)
                        continue;

                    result = tag.Description;
                    return true;
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Because this suggested solution is iterating through the directories looking for the right tag, I'm not sure it's the best approach on the grounds that it's inefficient from a CPU cycle perspective.  In the grand scheme of things it probably wouldn't make a big deal to my solution, but nonetheless I think a better approach is to use the Metadata Extractor ```Get...``` or ```TryGet...``` methods.  
Having said that, I wouldn't have got to that conclusion without your and @Jimi comments, so big thanks.